# Predicate logic question

Tags: logic

[image]

I could not find how to begin to think about this question. Where should I begin to tackle this predicate logic? How do I get the truth value for them? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In the first pair the two are equivalent. Not so for the second pair.

Comment: For ii., let $Q(x)$ be $\neg P(x)$, and interpret $P$ so that it's a nonempty proper subset of $D$.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your own predicates and domain and test it out. This isn't perfect as the logic might not work out in general, but it can be a good start and help you see why a particular equivalence is true or false.

I suggest having at least one element in your domain for each combination of true and false for the predicates. So let's have $D = \{0,1,2,3\}$ with $P$ being true of $0$ and $1$ and $Q$ being true of $0$ and $2$. This way we have all 4 combinations of $P$ and $Q$ being true and false. Now check to see if your equivalences are true for this case, and also cases where $D$ is a subset of $\{0,1,2,3\}$.